# Finding indexof value starting from the end of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, function

I'm currently using the function below to look up values in my array. it works great. However i want to modify it to start from the end and get the last value that matches. Please help

```
Array.prototype.indexOfObj = function (key, value) {
for (var i = 0; i < this.length;)
    if (this[i++][key] === value) return --i
return -1
}
myArr.indexOfObject("key", "value");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply begin the for-loop from the last index at `this.length-1` to `0` and return the current position:

```js
Array.prototype.lastIndexOfObj = function (key, value) {
for (var i = this.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    if (this[i][key] === value) return i;
return -1
}

//                        0                                 1                       2 <-- here                  3  
let myArray = [{"key":"value", "foo":"bar"}, {"key":"value", "foo":"bar"}, {"key":"value", "foo":"bar"}, {"foo":"bar"} ];

console.log(myArray.lastIndexOfObj("key", "value"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate from the end by assigning `i` the current length, and subtracting 'till `0`:

```js
Array.prototype.lastIndexOfObj = function(key, value) {
  for (var i = this.length; i--;) {
    if(this[i][key] === value) return i;
  }
    
  return -1;
}

var myArr = [{ key: 'value' }, { key: 'not value' }, { key: 'value' }, { key: 'not value' }];

console.log(myArr.lastIndexOfObj("key", "value"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```